# How do I generate two correlated Poisson random variables?

Tags: distributions, self-study, poisson-distribution, covariance, random-generation

How would I simulate observations from a bivariate Poisson distribution such that they have a nonzero covariance? The hint I was given is that I need to use the fact that the sum of two Poisson random variables is also Poisson.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108705.  Both answers there show how values can be simulated by means of three independent Poisson variates (although they do not explicitly point that out).

Comment: Please see the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). The hint you already have is a complete giveaway; I'm not sure there's much of anything between the hint you already have and telling you exactly which Poissons to add ... i.e. a complete solution. Oh, wait, there's one -- start with more than two independent Poissons.

Answer (score 9):

Since you do not impose any constraint on the joint distribution, any [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29) structure gives you a solution. For instance,

1. take a bivariate normal
   $$(x_1,x_2)\sim\mathcal{N}_2\left((0,0),\left[\matrix{1 &\rho\\\rho &1}\right]\right)$$generation;
2. turn $(x_1,x_2)$ in correlated uniforms as $$(u_1,u_2)=(\Phi(x_1),\Phi(x_2))$$where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the normal CDF;
3. derive two Poisson variates $(n_1,n_2)$ with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ from $(u_1,u_2)$ by inverting [the Poisson CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Generating_Poisson-distributed_random_variables).

Comment: +1 but could you maybe also add an introductory reference to the copula link? It's a wikipedia stub at present.

Comment: @conjugateprior: thank you, the link was damaged and I just corrected it to the entire Wikipedia page.