# Difference between $\mathrm{Poisson}(x_1)$, $\mathrm{Poisson}(x_2)$ and $\mathrm{BPoisson}(x_1, x_2)$

Tags: poisson-distribution, bivariate, multivariate-distribution

I am trying to find out the difference between treating two random variables as poisson distributions, $\mathrm{Poisson}(x_1)$, $\mathrm{Poisson}(x_2)$, and using a bivariate poisson,  $\mathrm{BPoisson}(x_1, x_2)$.  I know the different forms these take but I am more interested in understanding the different assumptions behind their use.

Comment: Can you say more, or provide some context/ an e?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any multivariate distribution describes [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) of some variables. Karlis and Ntzoufras (2003) define bivariate Poisson distribution pmf as

$$
f(x,y) = \exp\{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)\}
\frac{\lambda_1^x}{x!}
\frac{\lambda_2^y}{y!}
\sum^{\min(x,y)}_{k=0}
{x \choose k}
{y \choose k}
k!\left(\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1\lambda_2}\right)^k
$$

$E(X) = \lambda_1+\lambda_3$ and $E(Y) = \lambda_2+\lambda_3$, where $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y) = \lambda_3$, so you can treat $\lambda_3$ as a measure of dependence between the two [marginal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) Poisson distributions. Example of such distribution is plotted below.

[image]

and two marginal distributions

[image]

by marginal distribution we mean how would joint distribution "look like" if we looked at it "from the $X$ side", or "from the $Y$ side". Marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are Poisson distributions with parameters $\lambda_X = \lambda_1+\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_Y = \lambda_2+\lambda_3$.

What is different from looking only at two *independent* Poisson distributions is that we do not account anyhow for [dependence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/covariance-and-independence) between them (i.e. we assume $\lambda_3 = 0$). Using bivariate distribution lets you account for [covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29713/what-is-covariance-in-plain-language) between $X$ and $Y$.

Check also the following threads [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d) and [Deriving the bivariate Poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108705/deriving-the-bivariate-poisson-distribution)

---

Karlis, D., & Ntzoufras, I. (2003). [Analysis of sports data by using bivariate Poisson models.](http://stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jbn/papers2/08_Karlis_Ntzoufras_2003_RSSD.pdf) *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series D (The Statistician), 52*(3), 381-393.

Comment: Plotting these discrete distributions with continuous curves and surfaces, as if they had PDFs, may mislead people.

Comment: @whuber I totally agree but it is much easier like this and the resulting plot is much more readable.

Comment: Why not use a barplot-like visualization to emphasize the discreteness?

Comment: Great answer.  Could I possibly ask a follow up - is it clear from f(x, y) that lambda_3 is the covariance of X and Y?

Comment: @JMzance I do not understand your question... $\lambda_3$ is a parameter of this distribution.

Comment: Ok so the $\lambda_3$ isnt related to the amount of dependence between X and Y?  Also for what its worth I disagree with @whuber - it was much easier to see the plots when they were continuous - especially the 3D one

Comment: Basically I'm asking how you would show cov(X, Y) = $\lambda_3$ from the definition of f(x,y)

Comment: @JMzance no big math is needed here: bivariate Poisson is constructed from three independent Poisson distributed variables $X',Y',Z$ so that $X=X'+Z$ and $Y=Y'+Z$ with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$. So $Z$ is the "common thing" that is added to $X'$ and $Y'$...