# How to generate random samples for the Poisson Bivariate Distribution like `np.random.poisson` in Numpy?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, poisson-distribution, monte-carlo, bivariate

I am working with the Poisson Bivariate Distribution and I need to generate random samples to apply in a Monte Carlo simulation, but so far I haven't found too much about it on the internet. I saw that Numpy can generate random samples for the standard Poisson Distribution ( `np.random.poisson` ), but not for the Bivariate.

Comment: Perhaps this could help: [Bivariate Poisson Distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442916/bivariate-poisson-distribution-in-python)

Comment: Also, scipy.stats libraries are generally more versatile than numpy (you can generate samples, get pdf and cdf, etc.) See, e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html

Comment: Re "haven't found too much about it:" have you considered searching our site?  Your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108705/deriving-the-bivariate-poisson-distribution.  See the first line of [my post there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/108713/919).